# Difference between a priori and a posteriori estimates for some PDEs

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question

Consider the following PDEs in $(0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$:

\begin{align*}
(1)& \quad u_t + uu_x - u_{xx} =0 \\
(2)& \quad u_t + uu_x  =0 \\
(3)& \quad u_t - u_{xx} =0
\end{align*}
with initial condition $u(0,x) = g(x)$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

What are (and what is the difference between) *a priori* and *a posteriori* estimates for the solutions of these PDEs? Can you point out some references on these kinds of estimates for the problems above and possibly more general ones?

Comment: This post may be helpful, even if it doesn't address the question about references: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/23202/what-are-differences-between-a-priori-and-posteriori-error-estimate-in-numer